# How to combine ifelse statement with grep?

Tags: r

I have a list of foods that I need to create an overarching category column for. An example of my food sources are below:

```
FruitSources <- c("Apple Juice", "Apple Puree", "Apple Pieces", "Orange Juice", "Orange Pieces", "Banana Smoothie", "Banana Pieces", 
                  "Apple & Blackcurrant Juice", "Mango & Banana Smoothie", "Watermelon, Apple & Orange Juice")
```

I wish to create this category using the very first word only for each entry in `FruitSources` and not the entire row. For example, my anticipated output would be:

```
Categories <- c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange", "Banana", "Banana", "Apple", "Other", "Other")
```

Although some entries have an `&` symbol which would likely result in `Other`, I would prefer a solution that uses the very first word only. In my example above, any fruit other than apple, orange and banana would result in "Other". A crude way to do this would be:

```
Output <- ifelse(FruitSources=='Apple', 'Apple',
                 ifelse(FruitSources=='Banana', 'Banana',
                        ifelse(FruitSources=='Orange', 'Orange', 'Other')))
```

However, the above does not detect the first word only and instead, searches for the entire string. This results in:

```
Output
 [1] "Other" "Other" "Other" "Other" "Other" "Other" "Other" "Other" "Other" "Other"
```

I have used nested ifelse statements before, but is it possible to combine them with grep and complete the above?

Comment: My sincere apologies, I understand this is frustrating!

Comment: Because that is the source it originates from. Is there a way I can search for the first entry of apple, orange and banana, classifying these as such in the FruitSources and anything else as other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that for all strings that have `&` or `,` should have "Other" as expected and all others, the first word, then use `grepl` to generate logical vector based on `&` and with `ifelse` and `word` (from `stringr`) get the first word if there is no `&`, `,` or else return as "Other"

```
library(stringr)
ifelse(grepl("[&,]", FruitSources), "Other", word(FruitSources, 1))
#[1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Apple"  "Orange" "Orange" "Banana" 
#[7] "Banana" "Other"  "Other"  "Other"
```

---

If this is based on single 'Fruit' vs multiple 'Fruits', then one option is `str_count` to generate the logical index

```
ifelse(str_count(FruitSources, "\\b(Apple|Orange|Banana|Mango|Blackcurrant)\\b")==1, 
                     word(FruitSources, 1), "Other")
#[1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Apple"  "Orange" "Orange" "Banana" 
#[7] "Banana" "Other"  "Other"  "Other"
```

---

#### Update

If this is based on the first entry words as 'Apple', 'Orange' or 'Banana'

```
ifelse(grepl("^(Apple|Orange|Banana)", FruitSources),  word(FruitSources, 1), "Other")
#[1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Apple"  "Orange" "Orange" "Banana" 
#[7] "Banana" "Apple"  "Other"  "Other"
```

Comment: Beautiful and simple!

Comment: To cover the possibility, if there was no `&` symbol?

Comment: @user2716568  Then, you may need a pattern to show all Fruits i.e. `str_count(FruitSources, "\\b(Apple|Orange|Banana|Mango|Blackcurrant)\\b")==1` instead of `grepl`

Comment: Apologies but I have edited the post to show how your suggested answer doesn't work for `Apple & Blackcurrant Juice` which should be classified as `Apple` and not `Other.` Sorry for the updates, I should have considered this in my original post.

Comment: @user2716568  Why it should be classified as `Apple`.  I don't understand the logic

Comment: Because that is the source it originates from. Is there a way I can search for the first entry of apple, orange and banana, classifying these as such in the FruitSources and anything else as other?

Comment: @user2716568  Got it.  Updated the post

Comment: Thank you so very much, that is perfect! I appreciate your kind patience :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with regular expressions in base R.

It is based on two steps. First, extract the keywords in the first position and replace other strings with the empty string.

```
tmp <- sub("^(?:(Apple|Orange|Banana)|.?).*", "\\1", FruitSources)
# [1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Apple"  "Orange" "Orange" "Banana" "Banana" "Apple"  ""       ""
```

Second, replace the empty string with `"Other"`.

```
sub("^$", "Other", tmp)
# [1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Apple"  "Orange" "Orange" "Banana" "Banana" "Apple"  "Other"  "Other"
```

---

In one line:

```
sub("^$", "Other", sub("^(?:(Apple|Orange|Banana)|.?).*", "\\1", FruitSources))
```